# Standard terminology for a particular vertex

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, terminology

In a graph $G$ if $v$ is a vertex such that $v$ is matched in every maximum matching, then is $v$ of a special importance in graph theory?

Is there any standard name for such vertex?

Comment: Such vertices are often called "essential" or "match-critical".

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk, would you please direct me towards a reference of such vertex.

Comment: Definition 9 in http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~ksmani/courses/su01/combopt/lecnotes/lecture11.pdf is one of them, but if you google for "essential" and "maximum matching" you find many more.